# foreach plus for in php

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

I would like make:

```
aaa | bbb | ccc | ddd  etc
1   |  1  |  1  | 1 
2   |  2  |  2  | 2 
3   |  3  |  3  | 3
etc
```

for aaa, bbb etc i use FOREACH

```
<table><tr>
foreach ($data as $d){
echo "<td>" . $d . "</td>";
}
</tr>

for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++){
 echo "<tr><td>" . $i . "</td></tr>";
}
```

but this working not ok. how can i use loop FOR for all data from foreach?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "this working not ok" ... Are you receiving an error message? If so, please post it. If the output you're getting doesn't look how you expect it to look, please post a snippet of that output.

Comment: Where is your data for the table rows? It's not just 1111,2222,3333 as default prefill, right?

Comment: this generated 1,2,3,4 etc only for aaa. i want generate this with loop FOR for all data from FOREACH - aaa, bbb, ccc etc

Comment: @djot i want use for this example only 111 generated from FOR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can generate your table like this:

```
$columns = array('aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd');
$num_cols = count($columns);
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
foreach($columns as $col)
{
   echo "<td>$col</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";

for($i=1;$i<20;$i++)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    for($j=0;$j<$num_cols;$j++)
    {
      echo "<td>$i</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
 }

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: @eueka: And now just make $j<3 flexible, using a count() on $columns somewhere outside the for loop.

Comment: seems you forgot about starting `<tr>`

Comment: this is incorrect, the array count is always = $j+1 in this case

Answer (score 2):

In general depends on what `$data` looks like.

```
<?php

$data = array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'); // Assuming that $data is a columns storage
$rows = 10; // $rows = count($data); if you wish to have same number of columns and rows

echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
foreach ($data AS $item)
{
    echo '<td>' . $item . '</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
for ($idx = 0; $idx < $rows; $idx++)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($col = 1, $col_num = count($data); $col <= $col_num; $col++)
    {
        echo '<td>' . $idx . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';

?>
```

P.S. haven't tested the code.